# Eclipse GMF state machines with concurrent regions

Tags: eclipse, state-machine, eclipse-gmf

I am going to be creating a model editor, and I am considering using GMF. The editor will need to handle state machines (UML-based syntax, but not identical), which means concurrent regions.

I would prefer to model concurrent regions like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/aa/UML_state_machine_Fig4.png/660px-UML_state_machine_Fig4.png

Does anyone know if this is possible in GMF? I have been trying to find examples where people have done this and could not come up with anything. And I really want to know if this is possible (or requires a bunch of hacks) to implement before I begin development.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. It's a GMF feature called *compartments* which allows editors to have nested elements.

Take a look, for example, at:

1. [Hierarchical model in GMF](https://trac.rtsys.informatik.uni-kiel.de/trac/09ws-eclipse/wiki/Exercises/GMF/compartments)
2. [GMF tutorial](http://gmfsamples.tuxfamily.org/wiki/doku.php?id=gmf_tutorial7)